# ubuntu 17.10 conjure-up command not found

Tags: conjure-up

When I try to run conjure-up command . I get an error command not found. It was working earlier. Not sure what happened. Any guidance is sincerely appreciated

```
> $ snap list 
Name        Version              Rev   Developer  Notes
conjure-up  2.5.2-20180113.1501  924   canonical  classic 
core       16-2.30              3887  canonical  core  
corekubectl 1.9.2               303   canonical  classic
$ snap version

snap    2.30
snapd   2.30
series  16
ubuntu  17.10
kernel  4.13.0-32-generic
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run command with absolute path: `/snap/bin/conjure-up`

Comment: Or add `/snap/bin` to your `PATH`